# how to separate the first character of the pattern from the rest?

Tags: html, forms, design-patterns

I am making a form and in my form there is a field called username.
my username must follow a specific pattern:

- it must be between 8 to 12 characters
- it can be comprised of "uppercase letters", "lowercase letters" or "numbers" "_" "-" ".".
- the starting character must be a letter (uppercase or lowercase)

how should I write the pattern format?

pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{8,12}

i don't know the rest

please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var str = "_I.am-a..t3st"
var res = str.match(/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{1,12}$/g)
```

A playground example [here](https://regex101.com/r/wd9rF0/2)

**Edit on comment:** The first char restricted to be an upper or lower case letter.

Comment: thanks that works perfect. but I guess I made a mistake when I asked the question.

the starting character must be a letter (uppercase or lowercase)

Comment: Edited the answer, and I guess you'd better add that extra requirement in your question body. You know, when some another body heads to this question, it would be clearer then.